# C# Outbound HTTP Request Event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Windows Forms Application written in C#, it is a very big application with many business logic layers. This application is calling different WCF & REST endpoints/URLs. Is it possible to get a callback when there is a outbound call from the application? Modification of actual source code is not possible but any new source code for event subscription or callback is allowed.

I am trying to achieve a logging of network activities of the application with full details of HTTP and WCF SOAP.

Comment: Use an external program, such as WireShark to capture exactly what is 'on the wire'.

Comment: Perhaps the built-in System.Net trace logs will help. In your app.config you can specify a trace log that should include those requests. It is also possible to create your own TraceListener if the built-in listeners are close but do not log exactly how you are hoping. 

Network Tracing:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing

Trace Listener:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracelistener?view=netcore-3.1